# losetup encryption not working

Tags: 10.10, encryption

I've got /dev/sdb1 encrypted and mounted as /home.

The following line is in /etc/fstab:

```
/dev/sdb1       /home           ext3    noauto,loop=/dev/loop6,encryption=AES128
```

and

```
#mount /home
```

works fine, but

```
#losetup -e encryption=AES128 /dev/loop0 /dev/sdb1
```

which I'm sure always used to work, gives:

```
ioctl: LOOP_SET_STATUS: No such file or directory, requested cipher or key length (128 bits) not supported by kernel
```

Does anyone know why? If the mechanism for aes encryption over loopback devices has been changed, how am I supposed to fsck such a drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, `-e` is shorthand for `--encryption`. Try the next command instead:

```
losetup --encryption AES128 /dev/loop0 /dev/sdb1
```

or:

```
losetup -e AES128 /dev/loop0 /dev/sdb1
```

References:

```
$ losetup --help
 -e | --encryption <type> enable data encryption with specified <name/num>
```

Taken from the examples section of [`man losetup`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/en/man8/losetup.8.html):

```
          # dd if=/dev/zero of=/file bs=1k count=100
          # losetup -e des /dev/loop0 /file
          Password:
          Init (up to 16 hex digits):
          # mkfs -t ext2 /dev/loop0 100
          # mount -t ext2 /dev/loop0 /mnt
           ...
          # umount /dev/loop0
          # losetup -d /dev/loop0
```

Comment: Oops. I feel really dim now. Thank you very much. Assuming you don't mind, I'll ask for this question to be deleted, it's just noise. But thank you!

Comment: Do not delete it, it can help people who look for the right syntax. This question is not dumb, [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5328252/427545) is.